# Indecomposability of local systems and vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a (connected) complex manifold, $L$ be a local system on $M$ and $\mathcal{L}$ the vector bundle associated to $L$. If $L$ is indecomposable, does it imply that $\mathcal{L}$ is also indecomposable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this does not hold in general. For example, there do exist irreducible flat connections on the trivial holomorphic bundle of rank two over a compact Riemann surface of genus $g\geq2.$
On the other hand, if you consider irreducible local systems with unitary monodromy over compact Riemann surfaces then the associated vector bundle will be stable, hence indecomposable.

Comment: Are there similar examples in higher dimension as well?

Comment: Yes. For example, you can take the product of Riemann surfaces.